# POST requests sometimes return code 302 and sometimes code 200

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel project, POST requests sometimes return code 302 and sometimes code 200

When the 302 code is returned, everything is correct.
But sometimes the 200 code is returned and **this causes the POST data to be printed on the page** and **cookies/sessions are not set**, But then, the SUBSCRIBE method codes are executed and the redirect is done.
This problem occurs in all POST requests, only occasionally.
And this problem only happens on the real server

How can this problem be solved?

form

```
<form action="{{ route('subscribe.save') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="enter email">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

controller

```
    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required'
        ]);

        Subscribe::create([
            'email' => request('email')
        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'ok');
    }
```

route

```
Route::post('/subscribe/save', [\App\Http\Controllers\main\IndexController::class, 'subscribe'])->name('subscribe.save');
```

docker logs -f --details php / (Logs)

```
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:27 +0000 "POST /index.php" 302 // Everything is fine
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:28 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:29 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:32 +0000 "POST /index.php" 302 // Everything is fine
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:33 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:34 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:39 +0000 "POST /index.php" 200 // Return code 200, problem!!!
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:39 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:40 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:48 +0000 "POST /index.php" 302 // Everything is fine
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:48 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.22.0.6 -  09/Jan/2021:17:58:49 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```